# List custom fonts in tesseract-ocr/langdata/font_properties?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, ocr, tesseract

I am using `Tesseract 4.0.0-beta.1-370-g8b64` on `Ubuntu 16.04` by building it from source. I've got a directory of font files, and it seems from the [documentation for fonts](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Fonts) that you need to list the custom fonts in `training/language_specific.sh` and `langdata/font_properties`. Also it seems that fonts are listed in `font_properties` in some particular format, however I can't find the format anywhere. Is there any link or instruction asking how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's described in Tesseract Training Wiki:

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdoc/blob/master/tess3/Training-Tesseract-3.03%E2%80%933.05.md#the-font_properties-file

Each line of the `font_properties` file is formatted as follows: `fontname` `italic` `bold` `fixed` `serif` `fraktur`
where `fontname` is a string naming the font (no spaces allowed!), and `italic`, `bold`, `fixed`, `serif` and `fraktur` are all simple `0` or `1` flags indicating whether the font has the named property.

Example:

```
timesitalic 1 0 0 1 0
```

Comment: how about new font not include in that list ? I ran in to forever loop when try run mftranning with font_properties like unknow 0 0 1 0 0.